# Rendering Materialize collapsibles within the React map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, materialize

I am trying to render React elements using the map function and I would like each of my elements to have a collapsible component (while using the Materialize CSS framework). However, I cannot get my collapsibles to work, i.e., only the header is visible and they do not react to clicks.

I have a hunch that this has something to do with event listeners, but have not been able to find a solution to my problem.

I have tried putting the < ul > tag inside the parent element (Parent.js) and attach the event listener to all 'collapsible' elements after they have finished rendering. The collapsibles were reacting to clicks (not expanding), but the console was printing an error message about missing classList for the Element.

How do I get my collapsibles to expand?

Thank you!

**Parent.js**

```
Results =  
    this.state.results.result.map(function(item, index) {
      return (
        <div key={index}> 
          <Result 
            title={item.title} 
            link={item.link} 
            snippet={item.snippet} 
            id={sessionid}
          /> 
        </div>
      )}       
    )
```

**Result.js**

```
<ul className='collapsible'> 
      <div className="collapsible-header"> 
          Hello
      </div>
      <div className="collapsible-body">
        <span>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </span>
      </div> 
</ul>
```

**Inside the Result.js element:**

```
componentDidMount() {
     $('.collapsible').collapsible();
}
```

Comment: g_stu, Please let me know if  you were able to use below library. let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Materialize CSS may directly not work with React like that. Have you tried the React-Materialize framework. It is a popular library using the materialize CSS integrated with React and they have the Collapsible element in their component examples:

https://react-materialize.github.io/#/collapsible

Answer (score 0):

First install the package:
`npm install materialize-css@next`

Then

```
import M from "materialize-css";

componentDidMount() {
  M.AutoInit();
}
```

Or

```
useEffect(() => {
 M.AutoInit();
}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer. While this code may answer the question, might you please [edit] your post to add an explanation as to why/how it works? This can help future readers learn and apply your answer. You are also more likely to get positive feedback (upvotes) when you include an explanation.